# Display pop up alert message for few seconds in angular 6

Tags: angular

I would like to display a pop up message : "Saved successfully" for 2.5 seconds. Below code actually displays the message after a gap of 2.5 sec rather than displaying it for 2.5 seconds.

```
this.someService.someMethod(data)
    .subscribe(someRes => { 

           
      if (someRes != undefined  &&  someRes ['status'] == 200 ) {
                
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.popupService.showPopupOverlay("Saved successfully");
       }, 2500);
      }else{
        this.popupService.showPopupOverlay("Error");
      } 
                
    })

public showPopupOverlay(message: string, config?: Object): Observable<any> {
    let popupDetail: any = {
      'message': message,
      'config': (config?config:{})
    };
    this.showPopupAlert.next(popupDetail);
    return this.callbackPopAlertObs;
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What methods does the `popupService` possess? `setTimeout` will act after the amount of time given as passed, it is not the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show it immediately. However, the hiding needs to be done in a setTimeout:

```
console.log('the data is saved  now');

let popup = this.popupService.showPopupOverlay("Saved successfully");

setTimeout(() => {
  popup.hide();
}, 2500);
```

I don't know exactly, how your popupService looks like and how you can hide the popup. But the code above shows  the general handling with setTimeout.